# How to use AWS lambda in python to run multiple functions at once

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I currently have code that gets back school data from a database and saves it to a csv file:

```
schoolID = '12345'

def getSchool(schoolID):
    School = SchoolsDB.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(schoolID)})
    return School
school = getSchool(schoolID)


school.to_csv(schoolID + ".csv")
```

It currently takes in a schoolID and runs one school at a time. I have tried putting it in a for loop so that it runs one school after another automatically, but I want to be able to run all schools at the same time.

I want to be able to use lambda to run all the schools at the same time, instead of one at a time. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: How does AWS Lambda factor into this? Is that code running as a Lambda function?

Comment: Have a look at: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/parallel-processing-in-python-with-aws-lambda/ - BTW are you using some sort Document based DB like Mongo? if you are, why not just make `schoolID` an array and `find()` all of them in one go ?

Comment: You could also create a lambda function which would distribute work to other lambda functions so kind of workers<--> manager scenario.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses. I want to make a lambda function, which sets off all the individual school functions like this one to run at the same time, but I don't know how to do that. @mrangry777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a purely Python POV:

It looks like you are using some form of MongoDB, rather than having the function take a single ID and executing each time, why not pass it an array and find them all in one go.

```py
def getSchool(list_of_school_ids):
    Schooldb.collection.find( { _id : { $in : list_of_school_ids} } )

school = getSchool(list_of_school_ids=["1234", "5678"])
```

Then just build a massive CSV where each row is your entry in `SchoolsDB` - I'm coming at this completely blind though.

If not, you could look at:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/parallel-processing-in-python-with-aws-lambda/

But my gut tells me its overkill for your use case :)

Comment: Thanks I do need to use lambda because my code is actually a lot more complicated with manipulating the data and other functions etc. But I just need to find an example of how to use a lambda function to trigger each individual school functions like this one, all at one.